# Embedded payments and 'This function is temporarily unavailable' error

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to implement Embedded chained payments.

I have downloaded PHP PayPal SDK and it works fine without embedded option. The problem comes when I try to do it embedded:

I get my payKey with sdk. It returns something like:

> Pay - Response
>   responseEnvelope.timestamp:   2012-09-30T16:30:09.512-07:00
>   responseEnvelope.ack: Success
>   responseEnvelope.correlationId:   297f1e4a38b63
>   responseEnvelope.build:   3779320
>   payKey:   AP-9EB01133M3012281Y
>   paymentExecStatus:    CREATED
>   * Redirect URL to Complete Payment

(href of the link: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-9EB01133M3012281Y)

Then, I copy the paykey (AP-9EB01133M3012281Y) and I paste on this html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js"></script>
<form action= "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay" target="PPDGFrame">
    <input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light"></input>
    <input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-3GH99339RW1696440"> </input>
    <button id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal"><p style="font-size:20px">Pay</button>
</form> 
<script>var dgFlow = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow({ trigger: 'submitBtn' });</script>
```

When I click the button, the iframe is shown right, but an error appears: "Transaction Cancelled. This function is temporarily unavailable".
If I click the cancel button, I am redirect correctly to my sdk page (the same if I wouldn't have do it embedded)

I am using sandbox.

Answer (score 4):

Not setting the senderEmail when you create the PayRequest message should resolve the issue.  It seems the PayPal embedded flow requires the buyer/sender to insert his/her email manually on PayPal.

Comment: Thank you! I was having a similar issue, removing `senderEmail` did the job.