# Completing a 'PAY_PRIMARY' using the embedded solution

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm generating a 'PAY_PRIMARY' payment on the sandbox environment and i can create the 'pay_key' fine. Now i'm completing the payment using the below code:-

```
<form class="standard" target="PPDGFrame" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay">
 <input id="type" type="hidden" value="mini" name="expType">
 <input id="submitBtn" type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn     /btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" value="Pay with PayPal">
 <input id="paykey" type="hidden" value="AP-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" name="paykey">
</form>
```

I've added the javascript file:-

```
'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js'
```

Now when I click the pay button i get this error:-

```
  Payment can't be completed. This feature is currently unavailable.
```

Then when I select the 'X' button in the top right corner or the return' button, the dialog just hangs with a whirl pool image.

Checking the console out i get this error:-

```
 "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://t.paypal.com/ts?v=0.1&t=1380906025458&g=-60&e=im&pgrp=main%3Aap%3Apayment%3Albox%3Aerror&page=main%3Aap%3Apayment%3Albox%3Aerror%3Amember%3A%3A&tmpl=adaptivepaymentweb%2FWEB-INF%2Fjsp%2Fpay%2Ferror.jsp&lgin=in&vers=member%3A%3A&calc=c1f319179a468&rsta=en_US&md5h=9f767dd14d98c57474b882de4e57f1d8&shfp=%7C%7C&usce=beta&pgtf=Sparta&s=ci&goal=event17&flnm=ap%3Apayment%3Albox&eccd=adaptivepaymentspartaweb.Error.AP_Error_AP_Payment_Request_Sender_Not_Allowed&aver=unverified&rstr=unrestricted&pfid=c1f319179a468&pt=Error%20-%20Please%20try%20again%20later%20-%20PayPal&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.secure4services.com%2Fquote%2Fview%2F128&cd=24&sw=1280&sh=1024&bw=385&bh=550&ce=1&pl=mediaplayer%2Cpdf%2Csilverlight%2CShockwave%20Flash%2011.8%20r800&t1=3&t1c=0&t1d=0&t1s=0&t2=443&t3=342&t4d=767&t4=828&t4e=61&tt=2485&teal=9Zxv3B1ZaHzISptPjo45xDM8cTNjqkfI0TbjQKKxOwqIhL9AKaHPh7VJFyEJt7YpOzzuxNnxVehw8tf7fkF5oCGNtV0z6yA3WhvfLCkKHiM_1418469bba5"
```

I'm very new to all this so please bear with me.

Please can someone shed a little light on things thanks.

Andrew

Comment: You've added wrong javascript file. It should be 'apdg.js' not 'dg.js' if you are using the mini-browser option of Embedded Payment Flow. 
source: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/#mini-b

That won't fix completely your problem, as I'm getting the same "Payment can't be completed. (...)" error message. But this is a step.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same trouble - you should remove sender's email from request.
Related question [Embedded payments and 'This function is temporarily unavailable' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666184/embedded-payments-and-this-function-is-temporarily-unavailable-error)