# How to get mobile browser view of PayPal Adaptive Payments authorization form

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm implementing chained payments using PayPal Adaptive Payments API. We have iOS and Android applications.
Authorization form on
 **sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=** 
looks ugly on smartphones (both iOS and Android):
http://cl.ly/Vhvu

User-agent is correct (I've tested it in Safari development).
Is it possible to provide parameter to show mobile layout of this form?

Anyway, I also tried to exchange this url with embedded payment experience:
**sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=**

but it doesn't work with any expType options always showing the error:
**Please try again later. Payment can't be completed. This feature is currently unavailable.**

apkey is definitely valid, becuase the same key shows authorization form if opening with "webscr?cmd=_ap-payment" url.

So, is it possible to get pretty look of Adaptive payment authorization form on iOS and Android and what method is better, classic (webscr-url) or embedded?

Comment: Have you solved that ? i am facing same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is caused by senderEmail. If you remove it from the request, it would work. Please read more here:

[Embedded payments and 'This function is temporarily unavailable' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666184/embedded-payments-and-this-function-is-temporarily-unavailable-error)

(PayPal should be ashamed of its user interface. Can't they afford a UI designer to design a responsive UI for their ONE PAGE payment? Embedded UI is full of bugs >.<)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually senderEmail was the cause of the issue with embedded flow. Now it works, but not correct again. At the end embedded flow doesn't redirect to callback urls provided when creating Pay request.